# Equidistribution and Smaller Sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, equidistribution

I have a question about equidistribution. In [Wikipedia, Equidistributed sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) shows in the equation in the definition that $n$ reaches almost infinity.

> I was just wanting to make sure if equidistribution worked for much smaller sequences, like that of only $100$ or so numbers or something like that. It states a sequence of numbers, but without any specific characteristics. And I assume that for the equation to be true $n$ has to reach near infinity, or else it will only work for certain instances and not all.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the definition on wikipedia:
A sequence ${s_1, s_2, s_3 ...}$, $s_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is said to be ''equidistributed'' on an interval $[a,b]$ if for any subinterval $[c,d]$ of $[a,b]$ we have:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}{ \left|\{\,s_1,\dots,s_n \,\} \cap [c,d] \right| \over n}={d-c \over b-a} . \,$

Your question is about a finite sequence (i.e., one in which the $s_i$ are not defined for $i$ bigger than some $N$). The problem is then that it is easy to find a non empty subinterval which does not contain any of the $s_i$ (e.g. take $[0, \frac{\text{min}\{s_i\}}{2}]$, if $0$ is not in the sequence).

For any of these intervals, the left hand side of the equation above will equal 0, but the right hand side is clearly $>0$, so finite sequences cannot be "equidistributed".

Comment: I think I get it. So a limited set will only work for some intervals, but not all. But with a near infinite set, it will work for any interval. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think I get it. So a finite set cannot be equidistributed because there will always be a subinterval where none of the numbers in the sequence will fall. But as n gets close to infinity, all the numbers in the sequence fall evenly in every subinterval. But there is discrepancy in equidistribution. Since n is technically a real number, there will always be a subinterval that doesn't contain a number from the sequence or doesn't have the same amount of numbers that falls in that subinterval as other subintervals. But since n is so large, the discrepancy is basically 0. Please correct me.

Comment: That is more or less correct. For equidistributed sets, in the limit, there are no non-empty sub intervals that don't contain members of the sequence. Note that the definition also demands that the proportion of numbers in each subinterval is in proportion to the interval size compared to the parent set.